# How to determine the length of time left to create an index

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a nonclustered index on a table with 100M rows at 35GB. The process started approximately 10 hours ago, and the database is still locked up.  I need to determine how much longer the process will take to properly set expectations with the customer.

Here is the code I ran:

```
USE [cpr_cc]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_wpi_documents] ON [dbo].[p_Patient_WP_Item] 
(
    [item_type] ASC,
    [context_object] ASC,
    [created] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [patient_workplan_item_id]) 
WHERE item_type = 'Document'
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [Workflow]
GO
```

Thank you!

Comment: It'll take until it's finished ..... but I really don't think there's any way to get a **number of seconds** (or whatever you're looking for) from SQL Server here...... if you need to set expectations with your customer, you'll need to try and run this operation on similar hardware with identical (or at least very similar) amounts of data and just time it.....

Comment: Unfortunately, I started the index 10 hours ago thinking it would complete in an hour or less.  Seems like they would have built in a way to monitor that.